# Razor email templates in .net standard 2.1 / Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to create a separate service for sending emails, this will be based on a .net core 3.1 application with its default layers (application, domain, contracts, infrastructure)

Within this project, I want to create a class library which holds my Razor templates and parses them so the application layer can send this as an email (both HTML and non-html) after the model has been applied, however this is where I run into a problem.

Every example I can find targets older .net core applications, which means nuget packages like RazorEngine.NetCore won't work.

Also examples as found in https://emilol.com/razor-mailer/ won't work as they target older frameworks.

A deep dive into the Razor Client Library also didn't work as I tried to adjust this sample for 3.1 https://derekarends.com/how-to-create-email-templates-with-asp-net-core-2-2/

Is there any way to make this work or do I really need to target an older framework just to create a email template library?

Comment: Try [RazorLight](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight)

Comment: Can you give more detail about what didn't work when using Razor SDK?

Comment: @Rosco which one exactly do you mean? The RCL? That does not recognize cshtml files and fails to compile afterwards. I am currently looking into razorlight but having difficulties compiling the templates on first run

Comment: The 2nd link in the question no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a simple solution for my Blazor application recently and found this GitHub project.: [BlazorTemplater](https://github.com/conficient/BlazorTemplater)

It's really simple to use.

1. Install the Nuget Package: BlazorTemplater
2. Create your Razor file with parameters for your template:

   ```
   <p>Hello, @FirstName.</p>

   @code {
       [Parameter]
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Render the Razor component to a string so that you can use it in the body of your email:

   ```
   private void SendWelcomeEmail()
   {
       string html = new ComponentRenderer<WelcomeEmailTemplate>()
           .Set(c => c.FirstName, Applicant.FirstName)
           .Render();

       Console.WriteLine(html);
   }
   ```